# Join запросы

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, подскажите, какова длина `Join` запроса может быть? Я так понял, `Join` соединяет таблицы. Есть ли ограничения у него? Или можно соединять в запросе, например, 5 или 6 таблиц=)?

Comment: Какая база данных?

Comment: База данных Mysql, или что имеется введу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Максимум - 61 таблица](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/joins-limits.html).

Comment: О_о серьезно...

Answer (score 0):

5-6 можно, пробовал. Но если таблицы большие, но запрос тяжелый получится. И обязательно соединяйте по полю с индексом.